# TabLayout middle tab not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout with fragments and for some reason my middle tab is not showing any info.
I get this warning message

```
/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for PlaceholderFragment{7ad7d52 #3 id=0x7f0d009a android:switcher:2131558554:2} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
```

After doing some googling, I came across this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202037

Unfortunately they say in that issue that it should not effect the view and is just a warning, but mine does not show the view.

this is my oncreate for the tablayout:

```
public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_days, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            case 2: View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page1, container, false);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.section_label2);
                textView2.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView2;
            case 3:
                View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page2, container, false);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootView3.findViewById(R.id.section_label3);
                textView3.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView3;
            default: View rootView4 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_days, container, false);
                TextView textView4 = (TextView) rootView4.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView4.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView4;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of the actual app? Theres not much to see, theres the 3 tabs, i have a textview that says something different in all 3, when i click the first one and the third one they work, but when I click the middle one I just get a blank fragment and that warning message comes up

Comment: did your recent comment matches with your question title

Comment: Fixed! I made a dumb mistake.. the layout height was set to 300 in that fragment.xml page.. Thanks!